# Optimizing while loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a piece of code that takes forever to run. Does anybody know how to optimize it?

The purpose of the formula is to make a column that does the following: when `'action' != 0, if 'PX_LAST'<'ma', populate 'buy_sell' with -1, if 'PX_LAST'>'ma', populate 'buy_sell' with 1`; in the other cases, do not populate 'buy_sell' with new values.

Fyi - Column 'action' is populated with either 0 or 1

```
#create column
df_zinc['buy_sell'] = 0
index = 0

while index < df_zinc.shape[0]:
    if df_zinc['action'][index] != 0:
        continue
        if df_zinc['PX_LAST'][index]<df_zinc['ma'][index]:
            df_zinc.loc[index,'buy_sell'] = -1
        elif df_zinc['PX_LAST'][index]>df_zinc['ma'][index]:
            df_zinc.loc[index,'buy_sell'] = 1
    else:
        index = index + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
import numpy as np

mask1 = df_zinc['action'] != 0
mask2 = df_zinc['PX_LAST'] < df_zinc['ma']
mask3 = df_zinc['PX_LAST'] > df_zinc['ma']

df_zinc['buy_sell'] = np.select([mask1 & mask2, mask1 & mask3], [-1,1], 0)
```

Comment: great stuff askshay. Thanks!

Comment: I am new - not sure i know how to do that. Is it accepted now?